# Is there any way to get "\n" from streams?

Tags: c++, string, stream

I am trying to work with a file, and convert it into some kind of data structure (Text is an "array" of paragraphs, paragraph is an "array" of sentences and sentence is an "array" of words, which are char*).

To make everything easy for myself I am using data streams (ifstream, to be exact), but one of the problems I met was defining where paragraphs end (2 '\n' is considered as an end of a paragraph). The simple way is to go char by char on with the text and check each one of them if it is a space or '\n', but that's long and kind of painful.

The code looks something like this:

```
    std::ifstream fd(filename);
    char buffer[128];

    while(fd >> buffer)
    {
        /* Some code in here that does things with buffer */
    }
```

And - well, it works, but ignores all paragraphs completely. `fd.get(buffer, 128, '\n')` doesn't work as needed either - it cuts off everything after reading 1 time.

So - is there a way to do this easier than reading char by char? Can't use `getline()` since the task forbids us to use vectors or strings.

**UPDATE**

So it seems that std::istream::getline may do the trick for me, but it still is not quite what I expected. It reads, well, first line, and after that something weird happens.

The code looks like that:

```
std::ifstream fd(fl);
char buffer[128];
fd.getline(buffer, 128);
std::cout << "555 - [" << buffer << "]" << std::endl;
std::cout << fd.gcount() << std::endl;
fd.getline(buffer, 128);
std::cout << "777 - [" << buffer << "]" << std::endl;
std::cout << fd.gcount() << std::endl;
```

And the output looks like that

```
]55 - [text from file
23
]77 - [
2
```

And - yeah, I don't think I understand what's going on.

Comment: Use `fd.read()` to get the `\n` characters go to your buffer unchanged.

Comment: Well, putting `std::cout << buffer << std::endl;` inside the while-loop doesn't output any `\n` other than `endl`.

Comment: You could always use `std::istream::getline`, which will read into a buffer.

Comment: @JamesKanze But consumes `'\n'` :-/ ...

Comment: `getline()` uses `string` which we can't use. `read()` works, but doesn't have that convenient ability to stop at a certain char. So I am trying to find something in between...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So?  His problem with `fd.get` is that it doesn't consume the `'\n'` (and that it fails if it doesn't extract any characters).  `istream::getline` will fail if it doesn't find the `'\n'`, but you can use `gcount` to find out how many characters it did read, and then clear the error and continue.

Comment: @Testie `std::istream::getline` does _not_ use `std::string`.  It works largely like `std::istream::get`, except that 1) it extracts the `'\n'`, so you won't find it immediately on the next read, and 2) it doesn't fail on an empty line.

Comment: @James Kanze Well, my g++ doesn't think so. I have just got this `error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::ifstream&, char [128])` , `note:   mismatched types ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’ and ‘char [128]’` and `note:   mismatched types ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’ and ‘char [128]’`. And cplusplus.com also says the same.

Comment: @Testie It's `std::istream::getline`.  So `fd.getline( buffer, sizeof(buffer) );`.

Comment: You are not calling std::istream::getline. You are calling std::getline. These are two different functions. (BTW cplusplus.com is bad, use cppreference.com).

Comment: @James Kanze I, uh, tried std::istream::getline and updated the question since there was something weird.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change back from fd.get to fd.getline. The difference is close to none though.

Comment: @Testie Judging from your output... It looks like you're trying to read a file written under Windows on a Unix based machine.  The strange output is due to the `'\r'` in the file.  The way _I_ handle this is to use a class `Line`, based on `std::string`, which has a `>>` operator which uses `getline`, then trims the `'\r'`.  Failing that: on your Unix box, there should be a `dos2unix` command to preprocess the input.  Or you can just ignore the `'\r'` when you've read them.

Comment: @James Kanze Thanks for the help! I will try to do that. Also - if reading char-by-char - will I still have to deal with '\r'?

Comment: @Testie Yes.  Basically, under Windows, an end of line is CRLF, which corresponds to `"\r\n"` under Unix.  And those `'\r'` will be part of your input.  (On the other hand, once you've read line by line, the `'\r'` are white space, and you probably want to ignore white space at the end of line anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you may not use any of the std containers.

So what I think is possible:

1. Read the entire file to a buffer
2. Tokenize the buffer for paragraphs
3. Tokenize each paragraph for sentences
4. Tokenize each sentence for words

For the first part, you may use:

```
//! Reads a file to a buffer, that must be deleted afterwards
char* readFile(const char *filename) {
  std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ifstream::binary);

  if (!filename.good())
    return NULL;

  ifs.seekg(0, ifs.end);
  size_t len = ifs.tellg();
  ifs.seekg(0, ifs.beg);

  char* buffer = new char[len];
  if (!buffer) { // Check for failed alocation
    ifs.close();
    return NULL;
  }

  if (ifs.read(buffer, len) != len) { // Check if the entire file was read
    delete[] buffer;
    buffer = NULL;
  }
  ifs.close();
  return buffer;
}
```

With that function ready, all we need now is to use it and tokenize the string. For that, we must define our types (basing on linked lists, using C coding format)

```
struct Word {
  char *contents;
  Word *next;
};

struct Sentence {
  Word *first;
  Sentence *next;
};

struct Paragraph {
  Sentence *first;
  Paragraph *next;
};

struct Text {
  Paragraph *first;
};
```

With the types defined, we can now start reading our text:

```
//! Splits a sentence in as many Word elements as possible
void readSentence(char *buffer, size_t len, Word **target) {
    if (!buffer || *buffer == '\0' || len == 0) return;

    *target = new Word;
    (*target)->next = NULL;

    char *end = strpbrk(buffer, " \t\r\n");

    if (end != NULL) {
        (*target)->contents = new char[end - buffer + 1];
        strncpy((*target)->contents, buffer, end - buffer);
        (*target)->contents[end - buffer] = '\0';
        readSentence(end + 1, strlen(end + 1), &(*target)->next);
    }
    else {
        (*target)->contents = _strdup(buffer);
    }
}

//! Splits a paragraph from a text buffer in as many Sentence as possible
void readParagraph(char *buffer, size_t len, Sentence **target) {
    if (!buffer || *buffer == '\0' || len == 0) return;

    *target = new Sentence;
    (*target)->next = NULL;

    char *end = strpbrk(buffer, ".;:?!");

    if (end != NULL) {
        char *t = new char[end - buffer + 2];
        strncpy(t, buffer, end - buffer + 1);
        t[end - buffer + 1] = '\0';
        readSentence(t, (size_t)(end - buffer + 1), &(*target)->first);
        delete[] t;

        readParagraph(end + 1, len - (end - buffer + 1), &(*target)->next);
    }
    else {
        readSentence(buffer, len, &(*target)->first);
    }
}

//! Splits as many Paragraph as possible from a text buffer
void readText(char *buffer, Paragraph **target) {
    if (!buffer || *buffer == '\0') return;

    *target = new Paragraph;
    (*target)->next = NULL;

    char *end = strstr(buffer, "\n\n"); // With this, we have a pointer to the end of a paragraph. Pass to our sentence parser.
    if (end != NULL) {
        char *t = new char[end - buffer + 1];
        strncpy(t, buffer, end - buffer);
        t[end - buffer] = '\0';
        readParagraph(t, (size_t)(end - buffer), &(*target)->first);
        delete[] t;

        readText(end + 2, &(*target)->next);
    }
    else
        readParagraph(buffer, strlen(buffer), &(*target)->first);
}

Text* createText(char *contents) {
    Text *text = new Text;
    readText(contents, &text->first);
    return text;
}
```

As an example, you may use it like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *buffer = readFile("mytext.txt");
    Text *text = createText(buffer);
    delete[] buffer;

    for (Paragraph* p = text->first; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
        for (Sentence* s = p->first; s != NULL; s = s->next) {
            for (Word* w = s->first; w != NULL; w = w->next) {
                std::cout << w->contents << " ";
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please keep in mind that this code might or might not work, since I did not test this.

Sources:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/

Comment: Oh man. I didn't think about tokens at all. Thanks a lot for the hint, I'll help a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. As a rule of thumb, whenever processing text, you must either tokenize it or use regular expressions. Also, I just tested this code. All you need to remember is that the paragraph tokenizer considers only UNIX line endings (\n). If needed, you may adapt for others formats easily: `if (end == NULL) end = strstr(buffer, "\r\n\r\n");` placing it before the `if (end != NULL)` inside the `readText` function.